# TypeError: can't convert Module1::MyClass into Integer, I can't find where is the error here

Tags: ruby

I want to compare an attribute of different objects in a different module of the classes of these objects, but I'm getting this error:

TypeError: can't convert Module1::MyClass into Integer

I wrote attr_reader :value, and when I write "puts array[0].value" everything is right. The problem comes with the loop:

```
num2 = 0
j = 0



for i in @array
  if  @array[i].value > num2
    num2 = @array[i].value
    j = i
  end
end
```

Comment: I only have an array of objects that below to another module, and I want to go through an array and compare one of the attributes of the objects with a number

Comment: "I can't find where is the error here" – Just read the error message. The file name, line number inside the file, and the name of the containing method are listed *right there*.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for x in y` loop, the `x` is not the counter, but the item inside the `y` in the current iteration. So by using `@array[i].value` you're essentially doing `@array[@array[i].value].value` which throws the type error.

You want to do something like this:

```
for a in @array
  if a.value > num2
    num2 = a.value
    j = i # what is this?
  end
end
```

Or you can also use something like `@array.length.times do |i|` if you want to use `i` as a counter.